# Button to call javascript with programmatical parameter

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I have some code on my view which works fine:

```
<button id="foo" onclick="myMethod('false', 'true');return false;" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-bottom:10px;" type="button">Not Present</button>
```

In some circumstances I want to change the parameters passed to myMethod, but when I try:

```
<button id="foo" onclick="myMethod('false', @Status);return false;" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-bottom:10px;" type="button">Not Present</button>
```

I get a warning of Invalid Character in the error list, and if I run it, then I have a blank space instead of the second paramter.

I could modify the code to have an if block:

```
@if{Status}
  .... Button with true parameter
else
  ....Button with false parameter
```

But that seems a bit off. So what is the syntax for mixing an @Parameter in with parameters for a javascript function call?

Comment: Have you tried '"+ @Status + "'

Comment: or @(Status ? 'true' : 'false')

Comment: The second one works, thanks @Cyberdrew

Answer (score 0):

Please use jquery to solve your problem i made this for you if it is not solving your problem please let me know ...

```
<button id="foo" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-bottom:10px;" type="button">Not Present</button>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#foo').click(function(){
@{
if(status)
{<text>myMethod(false,true);</text>}
else
{<text>myMethod(false,false);</text>}

}
});

});

function myMethod(var par1,var status){
//Your logic here
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Cyberdrews solution worked, though I may need to use yours elsewhere, as the above was just a small example of a complex page.